# Problem with C pointers

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I need to show use of pointers for my homework in order to receive full credit.

I have a problem with the pointers. My homework is about simulating the rabbit and the turtle race. The race starts at 1 and finishes at 70. Depending on the percentage of time that has passed, the rabbit and the turtle may advance quickly or slow, may fall of the mountain for a small or a large number, or the rabbit may be asleep. The race is over when one gets to 70 and the position cannot be negative (last while and ifs). The switches do everything related to movement. You'll notice because of the values inseide the switch if they advanced or fell off the road.

My problem is with the pointers. I must use them and they're f** me up! please help:

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{

    int x, post, posl, num1, num2;
    int *ptrt;
    int *ptrl;
    ptrt=&post;
    ptrl=&posl;
    printf("BANG!!!!\nY ARRANCAN\n");
    post=posl=1;
    do{
        num1 = rand() % 10;
        num2 = rand() % 10;

        switch (num1){
            case '0': *ptrt=&post+3; break;
            case '1': *ptrt=&post+3; break;
            case '2': *ptrt=&post+3; break;
            case '3': *ptrt=&post+3; break;
            case '4': *ptrt=&post+3; break;
            case '5': *ptrt-=&post+6; break;
            case '6': *ptrt-=&post+6; break;
            case '7': *ptrt+=&post+1; break;
            case '8': *ptrt+=&post+1; break;
            case '9': *ptrt+=&post+1; break;
        }
        switch (num2){
            case '2': *ptrl=&posl+9; break;
            case '3': *ptrl=&posl+9; break;
            case '4': *ptrl=&posl-12; break;
            case '5': *ptrl=&posl+1; break;
            case '6': *ptrl=&posl+1; break;
            case '7': *ptrl=&posl+1; break;
            case '8': *ptrl=&posl-2; break;
            case '9': *ptrl=&posl-2; break;
        }

        if (post<1)
        post=1;
        if (posl<1)
        posl=1;

    }while (*ptrt<70||*ptrl<70);
    printf("tortuga= %d\nliebre=%d\n" ,post ,posl);

    return 0;
}
```

the compiler output:

```
tarea.c: In function ‘main’:
tarea.c:17: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:18: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:19: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:21: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:22: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int’ and ‘int *’)
tarea.c:23: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int’ and ‘int *’)
tarea.c:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:25: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:26: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:29: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:30: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:31: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:32: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:33: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:35: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
tarea.c:36: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I think its because you need to derefference them before you try to manipulate them.

Comment: The '&' letter before all `posl` and `post` in switch is unneeded.

Comment: You must use pointers? Please, say exactly word for word what the teacher said about using pointers in this assignment.

Comment: Chris - I see... osgx - tnx... dialecticus - the teacher wants us to use pointers for this assignment because we need to "reinforce our knowledge about them"

Comment: I don't see why you're using pointers at all?  If all you need is some `int`'s and some random logic,  pointers will only get in your way.

Comment: pointers are a must in this homework, if this was java I would have finished a while ago :(

Comment: Is the assignment that you must use pointers, or that you must use pointers in a particular way? If the former, you can work pointers in by using arrays rather than switches. If the latter, teaching someone to use pointers unnecessarily doesn't teach them about pointers, it teaches them bad habits.

Comment: On another topic, your case statements are using character literals (e.g. `'0'`) when they should be using int literals (e.g. `0`). Also, you've left out cases 0 and 1 for the rabbit. If this represents taking a nap, it would be better to include them but do nothing, with a note explaining why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want just `*ptrt=post+3;` etc. instead of `&post`. Using the ampersand operator takes the address of the variable, so what the line is currently saying is "set the value that `ptrt` points at to be equal to the address 3 bytes past the address of `post`. Instead what you want to say is "set the value that `ptrt` points at to be equal to the value of `post` + 3."

Answer (score 1):

Notation int *ptrt means that *ptrt is an int... (or that ptrt is a pointer to an int... that's the same).
Here, you're trying to assign a pointer to an int (&post + i) to an int (*ptrt)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you want to write : *ptrt=post+3;  or  ptrt=&post+3;  instead of *ptrt=&post+3;  ?
&post is the address of the variable post, and post is the value of the variable post.

Answer (score 0):

Many points:
1 - Why you need pointers? You could just use ints... They are very simple.
2 - &var return a pointer for memory address of var. Keep it in mind. You cannot do &var+5 unless you want to access something in that memory address.
3 - *var = x set in the memory address stored in var the value of x. var still having the same value, but the variable stored in memory addressed by var will change.